# Excel text to appear on screen but not print

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am creating a contract in excel and I do not want the line item pricing to appear when printed.  Changing the font color to white is time consuming so not an option.  Hiding the group of cells would destroy the sheet when printed.  Is there a way to format the group of cells so the text will appear on the screen but not when it is printed?

Answer (score 1):

Use a cell (either out of the print range or on another sheet) to indicate if the price is shown. Then for all the cells that you want to hide, use the conditional formatting. If the cell is `true`, then show the prices, if the cell is `false`, then hide the prices. You would format one of the prices, then copy the format with the `format painter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro to accomplish this using the BeforePrint to run a script to change the cells to white then AfterPrint to return them to the original color.